In Dataloader.io all our scheduled tasks are failing, throwing an "expired" error
Has anyone seen this before? we have an enterprise account on monthly automatic payments, the error produced just says "scheduled tasks [task number] failed". We checked connection to our sftp server, all good. If anyone has seen this before is there a workaround?

I have same issue and following this thread in the dataloader community https://dataloader.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/6293223308179-dataloader-io-s-list-of-IP-addresses-to-be-allowlisted

You should reproduce the important parts of that link here. The link will become invalid at some point, reproducing the content here means your answer can still be useful after that happens.

We safe listed all the IPs in the internal firewall, port 22 open, ssh and sftp enabled, still no luck. They responded saying they're migrating infrastructure from Mule3 to Mule4, this is impacting many of their customers to this day.

Is the only error "expired"? It sounds like your session to Salesforce has expired: https://dataloader.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360042564473-Oops-The-session-for-this-connection-has-expired

the session was fine, it might be more complicated than that, looks like MuleSoft does not have a solution for this yet.

I believe an issue to sftp was resolved by MuleSoft, when I signed back in, saw this message.

